# Java - Is it possible to create a Comparator factory with an argument which changes the compare method?

Tags: java, factory, comparator

I have a class VectorClock which extends `ArrayList<Integer>`. I want to sort the elements, but these only have a partial order. A vector clock is greater than another only if all the elements are greater or equal than the other (and at least one greater).

As I can't directly use sort, because the order does not ensure transitivity, I would like to apply multiple sorts (one per index), successfully.

For this, I would like to make a comparator factory, which returns a class that implements `Comparator<VectorClock>`. It would receive an integer and return a class that sorts by the given index.
Is this possible?

Comment: All Classes are (essentially) factory classes because they return objects that are instances of that class (you can regard a Constructor Method to be Factory Method). Specific Factory Classes become useful when you what something that acts like a Constructor but may return Objects of different Concrete (underlying) classes depending on the context. A (native) Class X constructor only returns objects of concrete class X. It's not clear if you really need a Factory class in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't need a factory after all, I can just add a parameter to the constructor.

Anyway if it is possible to create a comparator factory, I would still be happy to know how.

Thank you.